# Python Social Auth redirecting back to https from facebook login

Tags: python, django, facebook-graph-api, oauth, python-social-auth

Facebook login is redirecting back to `https` URL when it should be going back to `http`

Correct URL: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/social/complete/facebook/?redirect_state=`

After Facebook login, the URL being redirected to is `https://127.0.0.1:8000/social/complete/facebook/?redirect_state=`

developers.facebook.com app 'Valid OAuth redirect URIs' is set to `http://127.0.0.1:8000`

I've also set `SOCIAL_AUTH_REDIRECT_IS_HTTPS = False` in settings.py but this hasn't solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I've also struggled to get facebook to work in dev.

I'm not sure if this helps your case but the only way I got facebook auth to work (in dev) with `python-social-auth` (0.2.1) was by adding a host in my hosts file (I'm on mac OS X so n my case `/private/etc/hosts`), like this:

```
127.0.0.1 www.dummyurl.com
```

And in the config (facebook developers app page Settings):

Basic:

**Site URL**

`http://www.dummyurl.com:8000/`

Advanced:

**Deauthorize Callback URL**

`http://www.dummyurl.com:8000/`

**Valid OAuth redirect URIs**

`http://www.dummyurl.com:8000/`

After the log in I get redirected to

`http://www.dummyurl.com:8000/#_=_`

However, I can only test this login with the **user that registered the application**.

Again I don't know if this helps your case I hope it does in a way that you can check a working app configuration.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer and I will try this. Strangely enough after rebooting my machine, the sign in is no longer redirecting to https...